# How to replace TCRT5000 IR sensor with TCRT1000 IR sensor

Tags: sensor, signal, signal-processing, infrared, light

I've got a pulse sensing circuit based on the [TCRT5000](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/377371/VishayTelefunken/TCRT5000/1) IR sensor. Its working fine and I can easily see the pulse when finger is placed. But I tried replacing it with the [TCRT1000](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83752/tcrt1000.pdf) but there is absolutely zero pulse. Why so? Below is my circuit, what do I need to change?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What current are you passing through the emitter LED in both cases?

Comment: @HandyHowie The same. I have set the pot to zero. Haven't measured the current though.

Comment: The two devices have different specs for the LED emitter.  You need to ensure that the LED current is within specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation by Vishay Semiconductors, both of these sensors are almost similar but TCRT5000 has a slight advantage to it due to a more concentrated beam emittance and acceptance angle. The document clearly states that it has an advantage in short distance operation which is true in your case since you are using it to measure pulse from a finger.

In my opinion, replacing TCRT5000 with TCRT1000 would not be a good choice but still if you have to do it, you can try changing the sensitivity of your circuit and see if it changes anything.

Here is the [link](https://www.vishay.com/docs/80107/80107.pdf) of the documentation I'm referring to.

Comment: Interesting. I was actually trying out TCRT1000 because (apart from liking it being more compact that TCRT5000) I thought with the exposed bulbs of the TCRT5000 its beam might not be as concentrated as that of TCRT1000.